# Plot points with big numbers

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to plot this figure:

[image]

The numbers in the y-axis are very big and an error is raised:
`! Dimension too large`. Another problem is disappearing `xtick` marks. In the following code, what must be improved?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}‎‎
‎\usepackage{pgfplots}‎
\begin{document}
‎\begin{center}‎
‎\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2]‎
‎\begin{axis}[%‎
    ,‎axis line style = thick‎
    ,‎domain=‎1810‎‎:‎2020‎‎
   ‎‎‎ ,‎axis lines=middle‎
    ,‎enlargelimits=true‎
    ,‎xtick={‎1814‎,1‎900‎,1950,1968,2000,2014‎‎}‎
   ‎‎ ‎,ytick={‎10‎‎,1‎00‎,1000,10000,10‎0000,1000000‎‎‎‎‎},‎‎‎ 
    ]‎‎
    \addplot [only marks] table {
1814,7
1905,8
1905,10
1930,7
1938,12
1942,16
1956,16
1958,64
1958,96
1963,10
1966,200
1966,512
1968,50
1978,256
1979,48
1982,640
1990,32
1993,32
1996,8000
1996,8000
1999,200
2003,2048
2003,16384
2005,12288
2007,1000000
2012,100000000
2013,1000000
2014,10000000‎0‎‎‎
};‎
‎\end{axis}‎
‎\end{tikzpicture}‎
‎\end{center}‎‎‎
\end{document}
```

Comment: You have hidden characters in your code ... Please make it compilable.

Answer (score 3):

After having removed the hidden characters, which were also pointed out by Zarko, and after adding `col sep=comma`, I do not get any `dimension too large` errors. However, to make the code more similar to the target output, you may want to use `ymode=log`, and rotate the xtick labels to avoid the overlaps. I also changed the `axis lines` from `middle` to `left`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16,width=12cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ymode=log,
    ,axis line style = thick
    ,domain=1810:2020
    ,axis lines=left
    ,enlargelimits=true
    ,xtick={1814,1900,1950,1968,2000,2014}
    ,xticklabel style={rotate=45},
    ,ytick={10,100,1000,10000,100000,1000000,10000000,100000000}, 
    /pgf/number format/set thousands separator={}
    ]
    \addplot [only marks] table[col sep=comma] {
1814,7
1905,8
1905,10
1930,7
1938,12
1942,16
1956,16
1958,64
1958,96
1963,10
1966,200
1966,512
1968,50
1978,256
1979,48
1982,640
1990,32
1993,32
1996,8000
1996,8000
1999,200
2003,2048
2003,16384
2005,12288
2007,1000000
2012,100000000
2013,1000000
2014,100000000
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks marmot, is it possible to have xtick without comma ","
e.g., 1900 instead 1,900.

Comment: @user108438 Yes, by adding `/pgf/number format/set thousands separator={}`. I modified the answer.

Comment: Nice answer (+1) ... I thing that he same result gives `semilogyaxis`. Does use `ymod=lo` has some advantages over `semilogyaxis`?

Comment: @Zarko I don't think there is an advantage, but I am not sure. In any case, both options are comparable in typing effort.

Comment: many thanks, again. dear friends, It seems that in the original figure the spaces between xtick are not real. Is a mechanism or a command that enforce it to new figure?